# Node Express "res.send is not a function" when used in middleware

Tags: node.js, express, https, middleware

My code looks like this:

```
const myMiddleware = () => {
   return (req, res, next) => {
    ...
    console.log(res);// this outputs only the locals set in a previous middleware
    res.send('not working');//send is not a function
  }
}
```

and its usage:

```
router.post('/route', previousMiddleware(), myMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
  doSomeStuff;
})
```

The previous middleware does an https request, sets the results in the res.locals, then the myMiddleware does another request somewhere else using the data from the previous middleware. I need to exit out of the whole route if there is an error in the middleware. It works in the first (previous) middleware function, but not in the second one. When I log out `res` in the previous middleware, even after setting the locals, it gives me the whole object with the `.send` method. If I log the `res` on the first line of the `myMiddleware()` function (or anywhere), `res` is an object with a single object property thats just the `.locals` from the previous middleware:

```
{ locals: { key: value } }
```

I have triple checked and I do not have the order of `req, res, next` mixed up.

Any thoughts as to why, and how I can fix?

Comment: maybe some code about previousMiddleware and myMiddleware?

Comment: Try replacing: `previousMiddleware(), myMiddleware()` with `previousMiddleware, myMiddleware` you need to pass the functions not execute them

Comment: can you show your `previousMiddleware`

Comment: the `previousMiddleware` is 98 lines long. The only time I reference the locals on the response object is here: ```res.locals.draft_order = json;
 // console.log('res object in first middleware: ', res)          next();```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass their names instead call them directly in router.

```
router.post('/route', previousMiddleware, myMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    doSomeStuff;
})
```

Because that middleware will be call when a request is send to server, not when server is initialized.

Comment: I just tried that; I just called their names and removed the `return () => {}` and I get the same error.